# Firebase iOS - does changing the App ID Prefix affect users

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an iOS app that is already configured to read and write data in Firebase.  The app was recently transferred to another Apple Developer account (owned by me).  Because the Team ID (App ID Prefix) is now different, I will need to configure the new ID in the Firebase console.  Since the bundle ID is the same, I can't add a second instance of the app with the new ID in the Firebase Console.

My question is: will doing this affect users who have a previous version of the app (which is configured with the old Team ID)?  If so, what is a strategy I could use to minimize user downtime?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Authentication user IDs, are based on the user account and the project. They are not based on the specific app ID.

For example: a user can create an account in a web app that uses the project, and then use that same account in an iOS that uses that same project.

The same applies if you create a new iOS app. As long as the app is in the same project, it will still be using the same set of users of that project.

Comment: Let me simplify my question.  If I were to remove the iOS app from the project in the console, would users that have the app installed still be able to access the project data?

Comment: I never tried, but I don't think so. But why not just leave both apps active in the project?

Comment: I ended up trying it and didn't affect any previous builds so there don't appear to be any issues with changing the ID Prefix in the console.  But the reason I couldn't have both apps active is because they had the same bundle ID (since the app was transferred from one apple dev account to another).